# Cloud ML Engine Prediction Service 'Read Operation Timed Out'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am running into some issues with my prediction service where I am getting the error `SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)` -- I am able to see from the [code](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L796) that the current `num_retries` is set to 0. Can anybody help me understand how I can update the `num_retries` so that more than 1 will be attempted? I am making my calls by following `predict_json` from this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/ml_engine/online_prediction/predict.py#L28).

Further, is there any way for me to understand if this read operation timeout is being caused by me (ie. something I am sending) or if it is caused by something on Google's side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the best approach to this would be to make the following change and updated execute() with `num_retries=n` where n can be any integer you would like.

```
response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': instances}
).execute(num_retries=2)
```